# Explicit binding required with MapBinder - Guice 4.0 beta4

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I tried to update my Guice version from 4.0-beta to 4.0-beta4 this morning and I started having problems with the MapBinder. I have a base module that extend JerseyServletModule. In the configureServlets() method, I do :

```
    MapBinder<String, ExportData> exportDataMapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(),String.class,ExportData.class);
    binder().requireExplicitBindings();

    bindCommonServices();

    install(new V8Module(exportDataMapBinder));
```

I populate the map in private modules, like this :

```
    exportDataMapBinder.addBinding(VERSION).to(ExportDataV8.class);
```

ExportData is an interface and ExportDataV8 implements it (I won't paste them to keep the question short).

It worked just fine using guice 4.0-beta, but with guice 4.0-beta4, I started having errors like this :

```
1) Explicit bindings are required and com.coveo.ua.data.export.ExportData annotated with @com.google.inject.multibindings.Element(setName=, uniqueId=2, type=MAPBINDER) is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.coveo.ua.data.export.ExportData annotated with @com.google.inject.multibindings.Element(setName=, uniqueId=2, type=MAPBINDER)
  at com.google.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder$1.initialize(MapBinder.java:380)
  at com.coveo.ua.config.UsageAnalyticsBaseModule.configureServlets(UsageAnalyticsBaseModule.java:223)
```

Anybody has an idea what I am doing wrong ?

Please tell me if I forgot to include important details.

Comment: This looks like a bug, if you can make a reduced testcase then report it at https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/list

Comment: I will make a test case and report as you suggested. If this is really a bug, I hope it is in beta4. Otherwise, my code should never have worked...

Comment: Also you can try the latest git, it may be fixed already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to [Guice 4.0 beta 5](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice40) and it fixed my problem. As Tavian Barnes suggested. It was probably a bug with beta 4.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your example that you are setting that explict bindings are required for your main module. Just remove that method and it will surely work. Do not know what has been changed in 4.0-beta if that code worked before.

Your code:

```
MapBinder<String, ExportData> exportDataMapBinder = ...
binder().requireExplicitBindings();
```

Should probably remove this line:

```
binder().requireExplicitBindings();
```

Comment: Removing binder.requireExplicitBindings() is sadly not an option. We use it to reduce the 'magic' to a minimum.